# How to prove this inequality using prime number theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Define $s_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number, now how to show that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf \frac{s_n}{\log n} \leq 1$$
I used the result from the prime number theorem: $p_n \sim n \log n$, but have a difficult time dealing with the $\inf$ part.

Answer (score 7):

Here we go:  $p_n \sim n\log n$, and $p_{2n}\sim 2n\log(2n)\sim 2n\log n$. So $$p_{2n}-p_n=(p_{2n}-p_{2n-1})+(p_{2n-1}-p_{2n-2})+\cdots +(p_{n+2}-p_{n+1})+(p_{n+1}-p_{n})\sim n\log n.$$  As there are $n$ terms and the average is $\log n$, one needs to be smaller then $\log n$, which means lim inf is smaller.
It should not be too hard to make this sketch rigorous.

Comment: That's pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with the infimum, remember that $p_n \sim n \log n + o(n \log n)$, see this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) for more accurate expansion.

The sequence $(p_{n+1}-p_{n})/\log n$ has [lots of spikes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Prime%5Bn+%2B+1%5D+-+Prime%5Bn%5D%29%2FLog%5Bn%5D). The infimum of this sequence would be the lower envelope for it. For sufficiently large $n$ 
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \inf \frac{p_{n+1} -p_n}{\log n} &<& \frac{(n+1) \log(n+1) - n \log n}{\log n}= \frac{(n+1) \left(\log n + \log(1+\frac{1}{n})\right) - n \log n}{\log n}\\ &=& 1 + \frac{n+1}{\log n} \log\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) < 1 + \frac{n+1}{\log n} \frac{1}{n} = 1 + o(1)
  \end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: The first inequality, which is the most important, lacks justification.